# Solution verification: How many elements of order 3 are there in $S_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, permutation-cycles

How many elements of order 3 are there in $S_5$.

I found it a several ways to solve this one. I did like this, but do not know is it correct:

I have a possible options  (a b c) = ( b c a) = ( c a b) ***(i)***, because it is cyclic. So now we have a to chose on 5 ways, b on 4 and c on 3 ***(ii)***.  Having on mind ***(i)*** and ***(ii)*** we have :

$$\frac{5*4*3}{3}=20$$. 
Is this solutin correct?

Comment: Seems correct to me. You should argument why all elements of order $3$ are $3$-cycles. I'd do this by using that any element in $S_5$ can be written as a product of $cycles$. The order of this product is the least common multiple of the lengths of the cycles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is correct.

I would have done it in another way. First you pick $3$ elements out of $5$; there are $\binom53$ such choices. Once that choice is made, you order them in every possible way; then you get $\binom533!$. Finally, since, as you wrote, $(a\ \ b\ \ c)=(b\ \ c\ \ a)=(c\ \ a\ \ b)$, you have to divide what you got by $3$. So, the final answer is$$\binom53\frac{3!}3=20.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The elements of order $3$ are the $3$-cycles.

There are $5\cdot4\cdot3/3=20$.  That's $60$ permutations of $3$ out of $5$, divided by $3$ cyclic permutations of each $3$-cycle.